# What happens to existing containers when swarm mode activated

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I want to activate swarm mode on a machine but there are some running containers on there. What happens to those containers if swarm mode is activated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They keep running normally in the node (computer/machine) they were initially in, but not in swarm mode, as they're not [services](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/services/). Even after you have a Swarm running, you can still create regular containers on each node of your cluster by using `docker run`.